# Is Removing vsftpd & ssh from init.d safe?

Tags: services, sysvinit

Everytime my system boot up, the ssh and ftp services are automatically start, is removing them from the init.d (init process) will solve my problem ? And is it safe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These services are not essential for the desktop. If you don't intend to remotely manage your PC or access its files, you can disable them. That will also make your system more secure.

```
sudo systemctl stop vsftpd.service
sudo systemctl disable vsftpd.service
sudo systemctl stop sshd.service
sudo systemctl disable sshd.service
```

Comment: How can I disable them ? when I use e.g `service vsftpd stop`. It do stop the service but after boot again it keep starting up automatically.

Comment: @nakE Specify your system/Linux distro.

Comment: My distro is Ubuntu

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: What is the different between `sshd.service` and `ssh.service` ?

Comment: *sshd service is originally written as ssh.service and sshd.service is set as alias name*: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978852/enabling-and-disabling-sshd-at-boot-via-systemd

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about scripts under `init.d`, this is SysVInit and not a `systemd` OS; so you're looking for the **`chkconfig`** command, which alters symlinks under `/etc/rc.d/rc*.d` named `S*` for start and `K*` for kill.